# Llenar arreglos en Javascript de forma recursiva, ¿Qué está pasando?

Tags: javascript, array, matrices, recursión, matriz

A ver, acabo de comenzar en Javascript, y estoy realizando un código que se encargue de llenar un arreglo de forma recursiva. La implementación de la recursividad está bien, porque el mismo algoritmio lo probé en Java y en C#, y se obtiene el resultado esperado. Excepto, en Javascript que solo regresa la última fila que se ha rellenado y con esa llena toda la matriz. Me gustaría saber por qué en Javascript me surge este detalle, en sí, no es un error, pero no hace lo que debería de hacer. Muchas gracias de antemano.

```
function main() {
  //Declaración e inicialización de la matriz de (3x3)
  let array = [3, 3];
  //Declaración de índices
  let i = 3, j = 3;

  //Llamada al método llenarUno() para rellenar la matriz array
  console.log('Expectativa');
  array = llenarUno(array, i, j);

  //Impresión de la matriz
  console.log('Realidad');
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      console.log(array[i, j]);
    }
      console.log("------");
  }
}

function llenarUno(array, i, j) {
  if (i == 0) //Caso base
    return array;
  else //Caso recursivo
    return llenarDos(array, i, j);
}

function llenarDos(array, i, j) {
  if (j == 0) { //Caso base
    console.log('---');
    return llenarUno(array, i-1, 3);
  }
  else { //Caso recursivo
    array[i-1, j-1] = (i-1) + (j-1); //Asignación de cada elemento de la matriz
    console.log(array[i-1, j-1]); //Impresión del elemento al que apuntan los índices
    return llenarDos(array, i, j-1);
  }
}

main();
```

Comment: Pues como expectativa yo veo que estas usando el metodo que "te da problemas" como ejemplo, y como realidad algo totalmente distinto, pero pues... se supone que segun entiendo si la expectativa es el resultado del metodo que te da problemas entonces el problema tecnicamente esta resuelto. osea, en si cual es la pregunta?, porque realmente no veo una comparacion plausible en este caso...

Comment: Por cierto esto en javascript no existe `array[i, j]`, no puedes seleccionar dos indices a la vez en javascript, seguramente te habras confundido con algo llamado `destructuracion`, que en tu caso no aplica puesto que cuando haces `array[i-1, j-1] = (i-1) + (j-1);`, solo estas asignandole a 1 espacio del array el valor `(i-1) + (j-1)` mas no a ambos espacios. el destructuring en ese caso no puede ser aplicado de esa manera.

Comment: Lo he comprobado en la consola, si tu en la consola declaras un array y luego pones `arr[0, 1] = 10;` y luego imprimes el array te daras cuenta que solo se le asigna el valor a el ultimo indice que definiste.

Comment: Tienes razón con las anotaciones que haces, estaba haciendo un mal manejo de los índices y de la declaración de los arreglos en Javascript. Sin embargo, mi problema radicó en la asincronía de los métodos. En breve, responderé a la pregunta con la forma que encontré para resolver este problema. Muchas gracias por tus comentarios.

Comment: No te confundas,  javascript es sincrono por naturaleza,  por lo tanto en este caso el tema del asincronismo no tiene nada que ver...

Comment: Javascript es síncrono pero NodeJS es asíncrono, y yo estaba usando NodeJS para interpretar mi código en Javascript. Ahora ejecuto mi código de manera normal, sin Node y me da el resultado esperado. Apenas tuve la oportunidad de editar el código de la pregunta.

Comment: Dos cosas: 1.Ese código no usa nada que genere asincronía, no veo Promesas o callbacks. 
2.Si has encontrado una solución, ponla como respuesta no edites la pregunta porque entonces se pierde sobre qué se preguntaba

Comment: Una disculpa, soy nuevo en esta comunidad, y es bueno que me aconsejen cómo formular y responder a mis propias preguntas. Parecería que tienes razón, que no hay nada de asincronía en el código, pero te invito a que ejecutes con NodeJS el primer código para que veas lo que sucede.

Answer (score 0):

Si estás utilizando NodeJS para interpretar tu código de Javascript, este es el código que me funcionó para resolver este mismo problema.

```js
function main() {
  //Declaración e inicialización de la matriz de (3x3)
  let array = [[0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0]];

  //Declaración de índices
  let i = 3, j = 3;

  //Llamada al método llenarUno() para rellenar la matriz array
  array = llenarUno(array, i, j);

  //Impresión de la matriz
  array.then(val => console.log(val));
}

async function llenarUno (array, i, j) {
  if (i == 0)
    return array;
  else //Caso recursivo
    return await llenarDos(array, i, j);
}

async function llenarDos (array, i, j) {
  if (j == 0) //Caso base
    return await llenarUno(array, i-1, 3);
  else { //Caso recursivo
    array[i-1][j-1] = (i-1) + (j-1); //Asignación de cada elemento de la matriz
    return await llenarDos(array, i, j-1);
  }
}

main();
```

Comment: Gracias, me sirvió de mucho

Answer (score 0):

Te he puesto el mismo código eliminando los async/await (son innecesarios). Obtienes el mismo resultado que con tu código:

```js
function main() {
  //Declaración e inicialización de la matriz de (3x3)
  let array = [[0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0]];

  //Declaración de índices
  let i = 3, j = 3;

  //Llamada al método llenarUno() para rellenar la matriz array
  array = llenarUno(array, i, j);

  //Impresión de la matriz
  console.log(array);
}

function llenarUno (array, i, j) {
  if (i == 0)
    return array;
  else //Caso recursivo
    return llenarDos(array, i, j);
}

function llenarDos (array, i, j) {
  if (j == 0) //Caso base
    return llenarUno(array, i-1, 3);
  else { //Caso recursivo
    array[i-1][j-1] = (i-1) + (j-1); //Asignación de cada elemento de la matriz
    return llenarDos(array, i, j-1);
  }
}

main();
```

Comment: No es por desprestigiar la respuesta,  mas bien una critica constructiva,  el codigo original del OP no tenia nada de async/await ni promises que volvieran el codigo asincrono, ese es el codigo original del OP,  pero tienes razon,  el resultado tanto en nodeJS como en javascript debe ser el mismo.

Comment: De hecho no,  me equivoco,  ahora que lo pienso el resultado no deberia ser el mismo... ya que ahora que lo pienso nodeJS corre en varios hilos, o bueno... quien sabe,  a vecez nodeJS es un poco impredecible,  me han llegado a pasar cosas raras en algunas ocasiones y en otras no.

Comment: No es nada impredecible y sólo hay un hilo de ejecución. La asincronía se ejecuta como una cola de tareas, cuando la tarea actual termina entonces se procesa la siguiente en cola.

Comment: Ummm entonces una respuesta bastante detallada que me recomendaron por ahi esta equivocada, ya que dice que nodeJS es multihilo, pero no cuestiono eso, no soy usuario frecuente de nodeJS asi que muchas gracias por el dato Pablo!, es util la informacion.